# Django, showing only matches condition in lookup

Tags: django, foreign-keys, filtering

I have a model in personnel apps, like this,

```
class Crew(models.Model):
    nik = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    isActive = models.NullBooleanField(verbose_name='Active')

class Meta:
    ordering = ('name',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I'm also creating a models in vehicle apps, like this:

```
from personnel.models import Crew

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    plateNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    regDate = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date')
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Crew, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.plateNumber
```

now I want to get list of drivers, where isActive = True in my lookup. How can I do this?

This is what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to custom the admin part in you app.

```
class VehicleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                                                                                               
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):                                                                
        if db_field.name == "driver":                                                                                               
            kwargs["queryset"] = Crew.objects.filter(isActive=True)                                                                 
        return super(VehicleAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)                                      


admin.site.register(Vehicle, VehicleAdmin)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Comment: where i should write that code..?
can you write a complete models..?
thanks before

Comment: if you are not familiar with django admin, you'd rather check the [official tutorial of admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial07/).

Comment: many thanks @newlife.. 
that's what i need.. you save my life. thanks...